# Histogram with log y axis in Julia Plots.jl

Tags: julia, plots.jl

I have tried the following:

```
using Plots.jl; gr()
histogram(randn(1000),yaxis=(:log10))
```

and it produces the following error

```
Error showing value of type Plots.Plot{Plots.GRBackend}:
ERROR: At least one finite value must be provided to formatter.
 in showoff(::Array{Float64,1}, ::Symbol) at /Users/ianmarshall/.julia/v0.5/Showoff/src/Showoff.jl:120
 in optimal_ticks_and_labels(::Plots.Axis, ::Void) at /Users/ianmarshall/.julia/v0.5/Plots/src/axes.jl:176
 in get_ticks(::Plots.Axis) at /Users/ianmarshall/.julia/v0.5/Plots/src/axes.jl:204
 in axis_drawing_info(::Plots.Subplot{Plots.GRBackend}) at /Users/ianmarshall/.julia/v0.5/Plots/src/axes.jl:452
 in gr_display(::Plots.Subplot{Plots.GRBackend}, ::Measures.Length{:mm,Float64}, ::Measures.Length{:mm,Float64}, ::Array{Float64,1}) at /Users/ianmarshall/.julia/v0.5/Plots/src/backends/gr.jl:570
 in gr_display(::Plots.Plot{Plots.GRBackend}) at /Users/ianmarshall/.julia/v0.5/Plots/src/backends/gr.jl:457
 in _display(::Plots.Plot{Plots.GRBackend}) at /Users/ianmarshall/.julia/v0.5/Plots/src/backends/gr.jl:1004
 in display(::Base.REPL.REPLDisplay{Base.REPL.LineEditREPL}, ::MIME{Symbol("text/plain")}, ::Plots.Plot{Plots.GRBackend}) at /Users/ianmarshall/.julia/v0.5/Plots/src/output.jl:120
 in display(::Base.REPL.REPLDisplay{Base.REPL.LineEditREPL}, ::Plots.Plot{Plots.GRBackend}) at ./REPL.jl:135
 in display(::Plots.Plot{Plots.GRBackend}) at ./multimedia.jl:143
 in print_response(::Base.Terminals.TTYTerminal, ::Any, ::Void, ::Bool, ::Bool, ::Void) at ./REPL.jl:154
 in print_response(::Base.REPL.LineEditREPL, ::Any, ::Void, ::Bool, ::Bool) at ./REPL.jl:139
 in (::Base.REPL.##22#23{Bool,Base.REPL.##33#42{Base.REPL.LineEditREPL,Base.REPL.REPLHistoryProvider},Base.REPL.LineEditREPL,Base.LineEdit.Prompt})(::Base.LineEdit.MIState, ::Base.AbstractIOBuffer{Array{UInt8,1}}, ::Bool) at ./REPL.jl:652
 in run_interface(::Base.Terminals.TTYTerminal, ::Base.LineEdit.ModalInterface) at ./LineEdit.jl:1579
 in run_interface(::Base.Terminals.TTYTerminal, ::Base.LineEdit.ModalInterface) at /Applications/Julia-0.5.app/Contents/Resources/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib:?
 in run_frontend(::Base.REPL.LineEditREPL, ::Base.REPL.REPLBackendRef) at ./REPL.jl:903
 in run_repl(::Base.REPL.LineEditREPL, ::Base.##930#931) at ./REPL.jl:188
 in _start() at ./client.jl:360
 in _start() at /Applications/Julia-0.5.app/Contents/Resources/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib:?
```

How can I produce a histogram with a logarithmic y axis using Plots.jl? I'm using Julia version 0.5.0-rc3+0 on MacOS 10.11.6, Plots.jl version 0.9.1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that you have an axis range that goes to zero, which is -Inf in log space.  There are a few ways to fix this, the easiest is probably to force a lower bound on the axis:

```
using Plots; gr()
histogram(randn(1000), yaxis = (:log10, (1,Inf)))
```

[image]

Comment: This is fixed now in Plots 0.11 - the code in the question will work now.

Answer (score 4):

As of Plots 0.11, the code from the question works

```
using Plots
histogram(randn(1000),yaxis=(:log10))
```

[image]